# Cannot find/retrieve older version of a question

Tags: support, editing

Ughhh I accidentally made edits and saved unintended changes to a question, and now I can't see the older versions. Basically deleted stuff and now it's gone.

Is there any way to retrieve older versions of a question?

Here is the question:
[Improving observable persistent queue mini-library](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/150192/improving-observable-persistent-queue-mini-library)

As you can see I accidentally deleted one of the two list items.

[image]

Comment: That depends, how shortly after posting did you edit it?

Comment: it's been about 5 or 10 minutes max since I edited it

Comment: I rolled that question back for you. In the future, you can click 'revisions' at the bottom of your post to see older versions.

Comment: ahh, thanks, I didn't know about that - is revisions available on all SE sites?

Comment: Yes, but you only have the 'rollback' option if you have edit privileges.

Comment: Yeah I am not seeing this revisions button at the bottom of my post/question

Comment: I will add a screenshot to this question

Comment: Click the "edited N minutes ago" link.

Comment: What @DainIIIronfoot said. Click 'edited .... ago' then you should see the 'revisions' *page*. My wording was mistaken.

Comment: oh np thanks let me try that

Answer (score 3):

To view past revisions of a question or answer, click on the link below the post that looks something like "edited *n* hours ago" or "edited Dec 3 '16".

Note that if multiple edits are made by the same person in quick succession, [only the last edit within a five-minute interval will be recorded as a revision](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/251876/148099).